# Text domain issue on ThemeCheck

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am running my theme through ThemeCheck ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/ )

One of the required fixes states:

**REQUIRED: This theme text domain does not match the theme's slug. The text domain used: This theme's correct slug and text-domain is my-theme-name.**

This is not a multi-language theme and I have removed all the translation from the theme, I have looked at all __() statements and _e and I believe I have successfully removed everything required for translation.

The error message should have a value after 'The text domain used: ' but it is just displaying blank too, which maybe means the issue is an empty '' in my code...?

The folder for the theme is correct and is my-theme-name

How do I find/fix this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [theme review standards](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/) **require** the following:

> All theme text strings are to be translatable.
>
> Include a text domain in style.css

You're receiving a warning because you're not following this requirement, and your text domain is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Theme check plugin required [__()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) function with your text domain.

If plugin can`t find __('string','my-theme-name') in theme files, he return error 
"REQUIRED: This theme text domain does not match the theme's slug"